# Count calls of a specific method of an external Java library

Tags: java, dependencies

I want to count the occurrences of a specific library call in all the classes of my project.

There is a way to get this number?

Comment: If you're using Eclipse you can right-click on a method and do "Open Call Hierarchy" (Or use Ctrl+Alt+H). This will show all places where this method is used.

Comment: Statically or at runtime?

Comment: statically. i need to count the times my project (not just a specific class) calls methods of a specific library

Comment: I'm not aware of any tools for Java that do that. And, if your code uses reflection, I'm not certain it's possible.